Намертво зависает компьютер flutter
При запуске даже пустого проекта (только что созданного) Завершая работу приложения компьютер намертво зависает, только перезагрузка помогает.
Ранее месяц назад все работала прекрасно. Ничего не устанавливал и не менял.

warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.



CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5600X 6-Core Processor 3.70 GHz
ОЗУ: 16 ГБ DDR4.
Displayname: Pixel API 35
Android: 15.0 x86_64

Кто-нибудь знает что это ?
Сносил Windows и ставил заново, проблему не решил.
Устанавливал все корректно.

а перевод на английский к чему?

Уже в первой строке лога -- Launching lib\main.dart ... Warning: ... говорится о несовместимости 3-ей и 4-й версий.

Попробуйте в терминале прописать flutter clean и  потом flutter upgrade. Проверьте Android Studio на последнюю версию, пересоздайте в нём Эмулятор. При этом Android Studio Попробуйте запускать от имени Администратора, если Брандмауэер блочит что-то, тоже ошибки выходят. У меня так было

Ничего не помогает, дело в эмуляторе.
До этого все работало прекрасно.

В логах видно что проблема в package_info_plus

Вы прочитайте внимательно что я пишу, потом отвечайте.

@aleksandrbarakin не все работают в стране крякощябр

Начинает умирать сразу? Похоже на утечку памяти или создание слишком больго количества потоков. Или битая версия флаттера. Это в отладочном режиме?

Да, сразу, я до сих пор не могу решить проблему.

Либо эмулятор выдает артефакты;
Либо эмулятор при закрытии apk приложения комп намертво зависает.

использовал эмулятор последней версии, android studio последняя версия, vs code последняя версия.
